# Yii2 create multiple instance from multiple model and with datepicker (kartik) on form

Tags: datepicker, yii2

I have a table on my database (`feuille_de_jour_responsable`) that is linked on 2 other tables (`personnel` and `poste_fdj`).

In a form, I use a calendar with "Multiple Dates Selection" from the Kartik's widget datepicker (http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datepicker#comments) and I want, for all dates selected on the widget, that a new instance "`feuille_de_jour_responsable`" will be created with the `Code_personnel` and `ID_poste_fdj`.

For now, the form appears but the button "create" do nothing.

[image: Picture from my form]

My form code:

```
<?php

$reqNomPoste = 'SELECT Nom_Poste_FDJ,ID_Poste_FDJ FROM poste_fdj';
$nomPoste = PosteFdj::findBySql($reqNomPoste)
->asArray()
->all();

//var_dump($nomPoste);

$reqNomPersonnel = 'SELECT Nom_Personnel,Code_Personnel FROM personnel';
$nomPersonnel = Personnel::findBySql($reqNomPersonnel)
->asArray()
->all();

//var_dump($nomPersonnel);

$form = ActiveForm::begin();

echo FormGrid::widget([
    'model'=>$feuille_de_jour_responsable,
    'form'=>$form,
    'autoGenerateColumns'=>true,
    'rows'=>[
        [
            'attributes'=>[
                'ID_Poste_FDJ'=>['type'=>Form::INPUT_DROPDOWN_LIST, 'items'=>$nomPoste, 'hint'=>'Choisir poste'],
                'Code_Personnel'=>['type'=>Form::INPUT_DROPDOWN_LIST, 'items'=>$nomPersonnel, 'hint'=>'Choisir Responsable'],
            ]
        ],
        [
            'attributes'=>[
                'Date_Calendaire'=>['type'=>Form::INPUT_WIDGET, 'widgetClass'=>'\kartik\widgets\DatePicker', 
                    'options' => [
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'todayHighlight' => true,
                            'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                            'multidate' => true,
                            'multidateSeparator' => ' ; ',
                        ],
                    ],
                    'hint'=>'Select Date',
                ],
            ]
        ],
        [
            'attributes'=>[       
                'actions'=>[    // embed raw HTML content
                    'type'=>Form::INPUT_RAW, 
                    'value'=>  '<div>' . 
                    Html::submitButton('Create', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) .
                    '</div>'
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]
    ]);

<?phpActiveForm::end();?>
```

And my Controller code :

```
<?php 
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\FeuilleDeJourResponsable;
use app\models\MeteoPrevision;
use app\models\PosteFdj;
use app\models\CategorieFdj;
use app\models\Personnel;
use app\models\FeuilleDeJourResponsableSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * FeuilleDeJourResponsableController implements the CRUD actions for FeuilleDeJourResponsable model.
 */
class FeuilleDeJourResponsableController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

/**
 * Lists all FeuilleDeJourResponsable models.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new FeuilleDeJourResponsableSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}

/**
 * Displays a single FeuilleDeJourResponsable model.
 * @param string $Date_Calendaire
 * @param integer $ID_Poste_FDJ
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionView($Date_Calendaire, $ID_Poste_FDJ, $ID_Categorie, $Code_Personnel)
{
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($Date_Calendaire, $ID_Poste_FDJ, $ID_Categorie, $Code_Personnel),
    ]);
}

/**
 * Creates a new FeuilleDeJourResponsable model.
 * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionCreate()
{           
    $feuille_de_jour_responsable = new FeuilleDeJourResponsable();
    $meteo_prevision = new MeteoPrevision();
    $poste_fdj = new PosteFdj();
    $categorie_fdj = new CategorieFdj();
    $personnel = new Personnel();

    if ($feuille_de_jour_responsable->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $meteo_prevision->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $poste_fdj->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $categorie_fdj->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $personnel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && FeuilleDeJourResponsable::validateMultiple([$feuille_de_jour_responsable, $meteo_prevision, $poste_fdj, $categorie_fdj, $personnel])) 
    //if ($feuille_de_jour_responsable->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $meteo_prevision->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $poste_fdj->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $categorie_fdj->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $personnel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && FeuilleDeJourResponsable::validateMultiple([$feuille_de_jour_responsable]) && PosteFdj::validateMultiple([$poste_fdj]) && CategorieFdj::validateMultiple([$categorie_fdj]) ) 
    {

        $poste_fdj->save(false); 
        $categorie_fdj->save(false);
        $personnel->save(false); 

        $feuille_de_jour_responsable->ID_Poste_FDJ = $poste_fdj->ID_Poste_FDJ; // no need for validation rule on user_id as you set it yourself
        $feuille_de_jour_responsable->ID_Categorie = $categorie_fdj->ID_Categorie; // no need for validation rule on user_id as you set it yourself
        $feuille_de_jour_responsable->Code_Personnel = $personnel->Code_Personnel; // no need for validation rule on user_id as you set it yourself

        $feuille_de_jour_responsable->save(false); // skip validation as model is already validated

        $meteo_prevision->Date_Calendaire = $feuille_de_jour_responsable->Date_Calendaire; // no need for validation rule on user_id as you set it yourself
        $meteo_prevision->save(false); 

        return $this->redirect(['feuille_de_jour_responsable/view', 'Date_Calendaire' => $feuille_de_jour_responsable->Date_Calendaire]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'feuille_de_jour_responsable' => $feuille_de_jour_responsable,
            'meteo_prevision' => $meteo_prevision,
            'poste_fdj' => $poste_fdj,
            'categorie_fdj' => $categorie_fdj,
            'personnel' => $personnel,
        ]);
    }
}

/**
 * Updates an existing FeuilleDeJourResponsable model.
 * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @param string $Date_Calendaire
 * @param integer $ID_Poste_FDJ
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionUpdate($Date_Calendaire/*, $ID_Poste_FDJ*/)
//public function actionUpdate($Date_Calendaire, $ID_Poste_FDJ, $ID_Categorie)
{       
    $feuille_de_jour_responsable = FeuilleDeJourResponsable::findOne($Date_Calendaire);
    if (!$feuille_de_jour_responsable) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The feuille_de_jour_responsable was not found.");
    }


    $meteo_prevision = MeteoPrevision::findOne($feuille_de_jour_responsable->Date_Calendaire);

    if (!$meteo_prevision) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The feuille_de_jour_responsable has no meteo_prevision.");
    }

    $feuille_de_jour_responsable->scenario = 'update';
    $meteo_prevision->scenario = 'update';

    if ($feuille_de_jour_responsable->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $meteo_prevision->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && FeuilleDeJourResponsable::validateMultiple([$feuille_de_jour_responsable, $meteo_prevision/*, $poste_fdj, $categorie_fdj, $personnel*/])) {
            $isValid = $feuille_de_jour_responsable->validate();
            $isValid = $meteo_prevision->validate() && $isValid;
            if ($isValid) {
                $feuille_de_jour_responsable->save(false);
                $meteo_prevision->save(false);
                return $this->redirect(['feuille_de_jour_responsable/view', 'Date_Calendaire' => $Date_Calendaire]);
            }
    }



    $poste_fdj = PosteFdj::findOne($feuille_de_jour_responsable->ID_Poste_FDJ);

    if (!$poste_fdj) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The feuille_de_jour_responsable has no poste_fdj.");
    }

    $feuille_de_jour_responsable->scenario = 'update';
    $poste_fdj->scenario = 'update';

    if ($feuille_de_jour_responsable->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $poste_fdj->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && FeuilleDeJourResponsable::validateMultiple([$feuille_de_jour_responsable, $meteo_prevision, $poste_fdj, $categorie_fdj, $personnel])) {
        $isValid = $feuille_de_jour_responsable->validate();
        $isValid = $poste_fdj->validate() && $isValid;
        if ($isValid) {
            $feuille_de_jour_responsable->save(false);
            $poste_fdj->save(false);
            return $this->redirect(['feuille_de_jour_responsable/view', 'ID_Poste_FDJ' => $ID_Poste_FDJ]);
        }
    }



    $categorie_fdj = CategorieFdj::findOne($feuille_de_jour_responsable->ID_Categorie);

    if (!$categorie_fdj) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The feuille_de_jour_responsable has no categorie_fdj.");
    }

    $feuille_de_jour_responsable->scenario = 'update';
    $categorie_fdj->scenario = 'update';

    if ($feuille_de_jour_responsable->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $categorie_fdj->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && FeuilleDeJourResponsable::validateMultiple([$feuille_de_jour_responsable, $meteo_prevision, $poste_fdj, $categorie_fdj, $personnel])) {
        $isValid = $feuille_de_jour_responsable->validate();
        $isValid = $categorie_fdj->validate() && $isValid;
        if ($isValid) {
            $feuille_de_jour_responsable->save(false);
            $categorie_fdj->save(false);
            return $this->redirect(['feuille_de_jour_responsable/view', 'ID_Categorie' => $ID_Categorie]);
        }
    }



    $personnel = Personnel::findOne($feuille_de_jour_responsable->  Code_Personnel);

    if (!$personnel) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The feuille_de_jour_responsable has no personnel.");
    }

    $feuille_de_jour_responsable->scenario = 'update';
    $personnel->scenario = 'update';

    if ($feuille_de_jour_responsable->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $personnel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && FeuilleDeJourResponsable::validateMultiple([$feuille_de_jour_responsable, $meteo_prevision, $poste_fdj, $categorie_fdj, $personnel])) {
        $isValid = $feuille_de_jour_responsable->validate();
        $isValid = $personnel->validate() && $isValid;
        if ($isValid) {
            $feuille_de_jour_responsable->save(false);
            $personnel->save(false);
            return $this->redirect(['feuille_de_jour_responsable/view', 'Code_Personnel' => $Code_Personnel]);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Deletes an existing FeuilleDeJourResponsable model.
 * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
 * @param string $Date_Calendaire
 * @param integer $ID_Poste_FDJ
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionDelete($Date_Calendaire, $ID_Poste_FDJ, $ID_Categorie, $Code_Personnel)
{
    $this->findModel($Date_Calendaire, $ID_Poste_FDJ, $ID_Categorie, $Code_Personnel)->delete();

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}

/**
 * Finds the FeuilleDeJourResponsable model based on its primary key value.
 * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
 * @param string $Date_Calendaire
 * @param integer $ID_Poste_FDJ
 * @param integer $ID_Categorie 
 * @param integer $Code_Personnel 
 * @return FeuilleDeJourResponsable the loaded model
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
 */
protected function findModel($Date_Calendaire, $ID_Poste_FDJ, $ID_Categorie, $Code_Personnel)
{
    if (($feuille_de_jour_responsable = FeuilleDeJourResponsable::findOne(['Date_Calendaire' => $Date_Calendaire, 'ID_Poste_FDJ' => $ID_Poste_FDJ, 'ID_Categorie' => $ID_Categorie, 'Code_Personnel' => $Code_Personnel])) !== null) {
        return $feuille_de_jour_responsable;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
}
```

If anyone can help me, I'm searching since 2 weeks and am completely lost ...

Comment: That looks a little complicated... Perhaps you can use Ajax and send request to controller's method that deals with incoming instance. And you just need to use `.each()` to get all values from datePicker... Something similar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
I see that is possible to use multiple instance and model but I don't see how to create the multiple model and instance on the same form...

Do you know if it's possible to stock the value of a `<?=form  ... ?>` ?

I will see for ajax.
But my need seems to be common in an application, It surprises me that it doesn't exist in yii2..